# How do I write an aligned function with η and arrows?

Tags: math-mode, alignment

I would like to know how to write the following function. Which command should I use?
[image]

Comment: This is an \eta.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: I'd like to know how I'd write it using latex commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align`-like environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \eta : G & \rightarrow \tfrac{G}{H} \\
         a & \mapsto \eta(a) = a \times H
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico: Not sure about `\colon`, but definitely `\mapsto`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, the function is an `\eta`. This is somewhat similar to Werner's answer except that instead of the (IMHO incorrect) `\rightarrow` in the second line I use `\mapsto`, and I try to reproduce your spacing (which might originate from an `eqnarray*` environment, but can be removed if you don't like it) and use a `*` as in your screen shot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \eta : G & ~\rightarrow~ \tfrac{G}{H} \\
         a & ~\mapsto~ \eta(a) = a * H
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses an `array` environment to organize the material. It also uses the macros `\to` (short for `\rightarrow`), `\frac`, `\eta`, and `\colon`.

The advantage of this approach is that it works even if you used symbols which, unlike `\to` and `\mapsto`, have different widths.

[image]

Note that I suggest using `\colon` rather than the more obvious `:`, as the latter is meant to be used as a relational operator, which isn't the case here. And, do note that I would make the spacing around the arrows much tighter than what's shown  in the screenshot you posted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for relational and binary operators

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{rCl}          % "right" "Center" "left"
\eta\colon G & \to     & \frac{G}{H} \\
a            & \mapsto & \eta(a)=a*H
\end{array}
\] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another trick that may be only for fun purposes!

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2.718281828mm,12pt,preview,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
  \eta : G & \rightarrow \tfrac{G}{H} \\
         a & \mapsto \eta(a) = a * H
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: How does your solution differ (other than in the document class that's in use) *in substance* from the one posted by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493452/5001)?

Comment: @Mico: Using `\[\begin{aligned}` and `\end{aligned}\]` adds more differences to his answer.

Comment: How is `\[\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}\]` *substantially* different from `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}`?